# How to get a node by a child node FIrebase

Tags: http, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database:

[image]

Based on this, how can I get a recipe, searching by a ingredient description using rest service in firebase?
I've tried it: `/recipe.json?orderBy="ingredients/description"&equalTo="teste"`

but I had no success.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries can search on values at a known path under the children of the location you query. Your values are instead at a dynamic path: the `teste` ingredient can be `ingredient/0`, `ingredient/1`, etc. That is a query that is not possible with the Firebase database.

With your current data a simple change to allow the query is to use the ingredient description as the key:

```
"ingredients": {
  "teste": 1,
  "teste2": 3
}
```

Then you can query with something like:

```
/recipe.json?orderBy="ingredients/teste"&startAt=0
```

In general this type of nesting of collections is discouraged with the Firebase Realtime Database. For more information, see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Well, the structure I need is: A recipe {description, level...} which has 1 or more ingredients {description, amount}. How do you recommend to structure this nesting using firebase database?